# Excel keeps crashing - Combing files

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below script to combine files in a folder after capturing file name in cell. It used to work fine but excel keeps crashing when I ran this today.

There are no syntax errors in the code. I am unable to figure out how to make this code run.

code:

```
Sub Button_Click2()
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range

    Dim TemplatePath As String
    TemplatePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path


    ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = TemplatePath & "\"

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 1

    ' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")

    ' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
    Do While FileName <> ""
        ' Open a workbook in the folder
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

        ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

        ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
        ' Modify this range for your workbooks.
        ' It can span multiple rows.
           Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                 After:=WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Range("A1"), _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:AA" & LastRow)

        ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
        ' be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
    ' data is readable.
    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Screenshot of crash:

[image: Pop up after the click on the crashed pop-up]

Comment: this is most likely (as in 99.9%) where your issue is: `SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit`. Adjust that to only AutoFit the columns where you actually have data. Asking excel to do work on the entire column set of a worksheet is asking too much. Even asking it to work on an one entire column at once sometimes is too much.

Comment: I've had a weird issue where a macro used to fail all the time. I found that if I closed Outlook when running the macro, it works fine.. Try that maybe?

Comment: If Scott's comment doesn't help, please go through the code step by step using F8 to find out which line causes the crash. Then please [edit] your question and include that information.

Comment: Maybe you've just hit a wall on the number of excel files in the source folder. Try removing a few to see if that's the issue

Comment: I think the message is very clear (which isn't always the case). You ran out of memory. @ScottHoltzman suggestion seems spot on. Try to `AutoFit` your range only and not the entire sheet

Comment: I commented the code with autofit, crashes again. 
Closed Outlook and ran the macro, crashes again. Used F8, no errors in the code.

Comment: @Majid - Try turning calculations to manual before running the code and also set screenupdating to false. Furthermore, try the suggestion of Nick.McDermaid and keep increasing the number of files in the folder until it crashes. And perhaps maybe there is one offending file that is causing it crash, with some trial and error you can find that as well.